# Is latest 16" MacBook Pro powerful enough to stream 4k video from Plex to AppleTV without buffering issues?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, appletv, cpu

**Scenario:**

I have a mid-2015 MacBook Pro running 10.15.3. I've downloaded some 4k movies to that computer. They're in MKV form. I use a program called Plex to stream the movies from the MacBook to an AppleTV. Plex Server runs on the Mac and the Plex Client runs on the AppleTV. The AppleTV is connected to a 72" Sony OLED TV where I view the content. Both the Mac and the AppleTV are hardwired to the network via 1gb Ethernet. WiFi never comes into play. The 4k video quality is absolutely beautiful and audio is fantastic too.

**Problem:**

Once every five minutes or so the movie freezes. Plex shows a temporary error popup indicating that either the network is too slow or the CPU on the Plex server isn't powerful enough to convert the file. After a few seconds the error message disappears and the movie resumes at full quality.
The problem can be eliminated by telling the Plex client to play the content at 1080p instead of 4k but I much prefer the visual quality of 4k.

**Question:**

**Will upgrading to the latest 2020-era 16" fully spec'd MacBook Pro (2TB SSD + 32GB RAM) eliminate the buffering issue when delivering 4k content from Plex Server to AppleTV?** Is there a way for novice consumers like me to figure this out on their own by looking at the more modern [Mac's specs](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/specs/)? It feels like my current 2015 machine is *almost* powerful enough to do it, but not quite. I'm hoping a Mac upgrade would solve the problem.

**UPDATE:**

The CPU specs for my 2015 Mac are: 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

The CPU specs for the current model Mac I'm considering for purchase are: 2.4GHz 8‑core Intel Core i9, Turbo Boost up to 5.0GHz, with 16MB shared L3 cache

Comment: My 2011 Mac mini is powerful enough to stream multiple 1080p HD videos to different ATV's in the house at the same time.  I'm fairly sure anything more recent than 2015 can stream a single 4K video, as long as your network isn't a bottleneck.

Comment: **HOW** are you streaming? WiFi or ethernet. WiFi is hared bandwidth and regardless of how fast the spec is ethernet is almost always faster. If it is WiFi try ethernet

Comment: @jimtut Thanks for sharing your experience. If your 2011 streams multiple 1080p videos to different ATVs, you'd figure my 2015 would be able to successfully stream a single 4k video. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @SteveChambers: 1gb Ethernet using CAT-5 cable for both the 2015 MacBook Pro and the AppleTV. WiFi is never used (for video streaming anyway) on my network.

Comment: Why isn’t the Apple TV playing the Plex directly? I send 4K to Apple TV from 2015 MacBook and iOS devices, Mac isn’t going to be needed or relevant if your Plex source can push the bandwidth required. (4K ProRes HQ basically saturates a gigabit network in prepactice) Do you know your actual data rate?

Comment: Are you using the Plex Server software running on macOS, or an attached NAS device with its own Plex SW?  For something different, try loading a movie into iTunes, turn on Home Sharing, and start the movie from the ATV’s “Computers” icon.  Same HW/networking as before, but different SW.

Comment: @jimtut The Plex Server software is running on the MacOS. I use iTune's Home Sharing option frequently for content actually downloaded from the iTunes store, but these 4K movies that are the topic of this question are typically in .MKV format, whereas iTunes prefers .MP4. I can't just drag it into iTiunes, unfortunately.

Comment: @ bmike Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question but the MacOS *is* the Plex source. That's where the Plex Server is running. As far as I know, the AppleTV is playing it directly. But whatever Plex needs to do to deliver the video to the AppleTV, it appears the MacOS doesn't have enough CPU bandwidth to handle it. Thus the freezes once every five minutes ago, the loud fan noise, etc.  Are you sure that 4K video would saturate a 1gb network? I watch 4k programs from Netflix on AppleTV all the time, and that's over a "slow" Internet connection (150mbs).

Comment: Oh, use Handbrake to convert one of the MKV's to MP4 format, then load into iTunes.  MKV's are HUGE, at least for 1080p content.  For example, a 20-30GB MKV can usually be converted to a 2-3GB MP4, and those are what I stream on my network.  How big are your 4K MKV's?

Comment: @ jimtut It varies by movie. But for example, one 4K movie that was exhibiting the behavior I described was the movie "Lucy." It's 8GB is size and it's filename indicates the movie is "2160p BluRay x265 10bit HDR"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up getting that new 2020 16" MacBook Pro and can conclusively say the answer is Yes.

4K .mkv files stream from the Plex Server running on the Mac to the Plex client running on an AppleTV box with no buffering/delays. This is over an Ethernet connection.